# TypeScript w/ React - Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof T'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a sorting function built with TypeScript and React Hooks that I am having some issues with.

Specifically I am receiving an error stating:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof T'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

You can see the sorting function and how I am attempting to test it [here on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-borg-xeoft?file=/src/App.tsx)

I am not really sure where the `never` would be coming from.

Any helpful links would be appreciated.

I will try to remove some of the unnecessary code but I have a bad habit of removing code which then changes the context (when using TypeScript) which results in a answer that may not be as helpful for my use case.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function SortByKey<T extends object>({
  data,
  sortKey
}: {
  data: T[];
  sortKey: keyof T;
}) {
  let sortable = [...data];

  sortable.sort((a: T, b: T) => {
    if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return sortable;
}

export default function App<T extends object>({ data }: { data: T[] }) {
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState(data);

  const sortKeys: string[] = Object.keys(data[0]);

  function handleClick(sortKey: keyof T) {
    setSortedData(SortByKey({ data, sortKey }));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sortedData);
  }, [sortedData]);

  return (
    <div>
      {sortKeys.map((sortKey) => {
        return (
          <button key={sortKey} onClick={() => handleClick(sortKey)}>
            {sortKey}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @c69 the provided sandbox link meets the **complete** and **reproducible** criteria. As stated, I am working to minimalize the provided code.

Comment: sure, but is it _minimal_ ? Not even close. If you cut the irrelevant code, people would be more eager to help you.

Comment: @c69 yes I agree and I am working towards a more concise example. Will update once I have that

Comment: @c69 the current example may be more ideal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `object` in "App<T extends object>" with `Record<string, any>`, ie:

```
export default function App<T extends Record<string, any>>({ data }: { data: T[] }) {
```

this will make `handleClick` of button.onClick stop throwing errors.

*Why: because when you ask for keys of `object`, they are empty by default, and there is no index signature as well.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `sortKeys` to `(keyof T)[]`:

```
const sortKeys = Object.keys(data[0]) as (keyof T)[];
```

But it doesn't look like a very useful type.

Comment: Doing  that leads to another type error in the `<button>` element.